# How to format HTML generated by php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, cakephp-2.0

I have a html code to be displayed in a particular `<div>` tag.Here is the html code:

```
<form id="web_formsGenerateFormForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/><h2> DETAILS</h2><div class="input text"></div></form>
```

I need to show it as aligned/formatted code . Is there any way possible using PHP/Cake PHP?? This entire html is generated by php and is dynamic. So I cannot add `&nbsp;` anywhere I like. Kindly give me suggestions.

Comment: What do you mean by "Formatted" code? Do you mean indented? Also why can you not place `&nbsp;` characters if you are generating the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\t` for tabs and `\n` for new lines

Example:

```
<?php
$data = '<form id="web_formsGenerateFormForm" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">\n
           \t<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="POST"/>\n
           \t\t<h2> DETAILS</h2>\n
           <div class="input text"></div>\n
         </form>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following at the start of the page before you output anything:

```
ob_start('ob_tidyhandler');
```

Have a look at: http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.setup.php